De-duplication while loading data from gcs to bigquery
We have a pipeline which will send all changes happened at cosmos db and store it in gcs as .json files (storage bucket) and from there i would like to load into bigquery by removing duplicates means only latest record needs to push into bigquery.
What is the best way to implement this?
Right now im loading gcs to bigquery, But how can i de-duplicate the records by scanning?
  BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

  TableId tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, tableName);
  LoadJobConfiguration loadConfig =
      LoadJobConfiguration.newBuilder(tableId, sourceUri)
          .setFormatOptions(FormatOptions.json())
          .setSchema(schema)
          .build();

  // Load data from a GCS JSON file into the table
  Job job = bigquery.create(JobInfo.of(loadConfig));
  // Blocks until this load table job completes its execution, either failing or succeeding.
  job = job.waitFor();
  if (job.isDone()) {
    System.out.println("Json from GCS successfully loaded in a table");
  } else {
    System.out.println(
        "BigQuery was unable to load into the table due to an error:"
            + job.getStatus().getError());
  }


By using a MERGE statement, this will allow you to only insert new records or update existing records based on the _ts value.

MERGE `your_dataset.your_target_table` AS target
USING (
    SELECT * EXCEPT(_ts) FROM `your_dataset.your_staging_table` 
) AS source
ON target.id = source.id  -- Match on your primary key
WHEN MATCHED AND target._ts < source._ts THEN
    UPDATE SET * EXCEPT(id, _ts) = source.*  -- Update if the source timestamp is newer
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ROW;  -- Insert if the record doesn't exist


